# Excel conditional formatting of groupings with a variable number of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a vehicle electronics inventory with a multiple and variable number of rows per vehicle representing devices installed in that vehicle that I would like to format with alternating colors per vehicle and alternating shades of that color per device, or if that's not possible I'll be happy with alternating shades per vehicle. What is the best way to go about this, and is it possible to set it up so I don't have to go through the reformatting if I add another vehicle or another device to a vehicle?

Alternatively:

How can I take an Excel sheet similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLPZ1.png) and automatically format it like [this (preferred)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KctMb.png) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LIQv.png)?

Edits:

Can I also do it while keeping the highlight duplicate values formatting?

In the images # is the vehicle number & not all vehicles in the fleet are included in the inventory, which is why not all numbers are represented.

Comment: Which column denotes vehicle? I assume it's column A, but what do those numbers mean, and why aren't they on every row? How would I know that row 7 and row 3 belong to different vehicles?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with four Conditional Format rules. However, you must first create a helper column for grouping every other vehicle. I don't know what data you have available, but this could be a simple formula, or rather, something slightly more complex based on your data. If you're not sure how, then open that as a new question with **minimally** reproducible data.

Below, column A represents the new helper column to distinguish each vehicle group (alternating 0 vs 1).

Next, select your data and then create Conditional Format rules based on Formulas.

```
    Light Blue: =$A2=1

    Light Orange: =$A2=0

    Dark Blue: =AND($A2=1,ISEVEN(ROW()))

    Dark Orange: =AND($A2=0,ISEVEN(ROW()))
```

[image]

The order of the rules does not matter. However, you later asked how to keep your "highlight duplicate values" rule. Well, we don't know what you are considering a duplicate (is it a single value, a combination of values, etc)? Regardless, just put that 5th highlight duplicate rule and move it to the the TOP of your rules. Then if desired, select "stop if true" box next to it. Again, we don't know how you want this to appear when duplicates are present, so adjust as needed.